# Request-reply with more clients and one server

Tags: rebus, rebus-azureservicebus

How does Rebus ensure that a requester gets the response destined for the requester from the server?

The context is a setup with multiple clients, one backend server and two azure servicebus queues one for the client side and one for the server side. One client's response must not be received by another client.

My concern is that Rebus doesn't support sessions on azure service bus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does Rebus ensure that a requester gets the response destined for the requester from the server?

Rebus replies back to the queue specified with the `rbs2-return-address` header in the request, so if you have multiple instances consuming messages from that queue, then the reply will likely not be received by the original sender.

That's pretty much how it works, so it's important that all Rebus instances that consume messages from the same queue have the same capabilities. This implies that e.g. keeping in-mem, non-distributed state in a process that may receive replies from requests sent by other Rebus instance is a no-go.

If you describe the problem you're trying to solve, then maybe I can give you some inspiration on how to solve it.

Comment: If the client queues are only meant to be used for request/reply, then you can just give them random names (e.g. a guid), so each client has its own reply queue. If you then remember to set the auto-delete-on-idle flag, the queues will be cleaned up when they're not used anymore. Look here for an example: https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus.AzureServiceBus/blob/master/Rebus.AzureServiceBus.Tests/WorksWithAutoDeleteOnIdle.cs#L34